# Creating appspec json file with codebuild (bash)

Tags: json, bash, aws-codebuild, buildspec

```
  post_build:
    commands:
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
      - docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
      - cat <<'EOF' > appspec.json
        {
           "\"version\"":0.0,
           "\"Resources\"":[{
             "\"TargetService\"":{
               "\"Type\"":"\"AWS::ECS::Service\"",
               "\"Properties\"":{
                 "\"TaskDefinition\"":"\"arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:414193698200:task-definition/deploy-wmi:1\""
               }
             }
           }]
        }
        EOF
```

Hi, how can I create an appspec.json build artifact in codebuild buildspec? I tried above and it doesn't work. The error is:

```
    /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: line 8: warning: here-document at line 4 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
cat: {: No such file or directory
cat: "version":0.0,: No such file or directory
cat: "Resources":[{: No such file or directory
cat: "TargetService":{: No such file or directory
cat: "Type":"AWS::ECS::Service",: No such file or directory
cat: "Properties":{: No such file or directory
cat: "TaskDefinition":"arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:414193698200:task-definition/deploy-wmi:1": No such file or directory
cat: }: No such file or directory
cat: }: No such file or directory
cat: }]: No such file or directory
cat: }: No such file or directory
cat: EOF: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried adding infront of { until EOF, but it also doesnt work:

```
    /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: line 8: warning: here-document at line 4 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
cat: {: No such file or directory
cat: "version":0.0,: No such file or directory
cat: "Resources":[{: No such file or directory
cat: "TargetService":{: No such file or directory
cat: "Type":"AWS::ECS::Service",: No such file or directory
cat: "Properties":{: No such file or directory
cat: "TaskDefinition":"arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:414193698200:task-definition/deploy-wmi:1": No such file or directory
cat: }: No such file or directory
cat: }: No such file or directory
cat: }]: No such file or directory
cat: }: No such file or directory
cat: EOF: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried putting all in one line ({"version":0.0,...) but my CodeDeploy said the template cant be parsed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [pipe's literal style indicator](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#812-literal-style) for YAML multiline strings.

```
post_build:
  commands:
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
    - docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
    - |
      cat <<'EOF' > appspec.json
      {
        "version":0.0,
        "Resources":[{
          "TargetService":{
            "Type":"AWS::ECS::Service",
            "Properties":{
              "TaskDefinition":"arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:414193698200:task-definition/deploy-wmi:1"
            }
          }
        }]
      }
      EOF
```

You could also achieve the same including a bash script in your repository to create the file and execute it in this phase. It will probably be cleaner that dumping your json file like in the example above.